# How implements a retry feature on bad http code with AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: java, android-async-http

I need to call an url and it's possible that call return bad http code like 404, 500 etc. I want to implement a retry feature when I get those errors: a new call will be proceed every hour and ten times maximum.

I use the async-http-client library to do my POST call async.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth considering the [Spring Retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/retry.html) functionality.

The API is constructed to be agnostic to *what* you want to retry, and concerns itself with retry policies, backoffs, limiting number of retries etc.

Another possibility if you're using Java 7/8 is the [AsyncRetryExecutor](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/asynchronous-retry-pattern.html). e.g.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
RetryExecutor executor = new AsyncRetryExecutor(scheduler).
    retryOn(SocketException.class).
    withExponentialBackoff(500, 2).     //500ms times 2 after each retry
    withMaxDelay(10_000).               //10 seconds
    withUniformJitter().                //add between +/- 100 ms randomly
    withMaxRetries(20);
```